# $log (or other services inside AngularJS directives)

Tags: angularjs

I have the following directive I use to initialize the [timeago](http://timeago.yarp.com/) plugin.

```
Directives.directive('timeago', function() {
   return function(scope, element, attrs) {
       $(element).attr('title', scope.post.utc_posted);
       $(element).timeago();
   }
});
```

How could I use/pass `$log` inside the function I'm returning?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can just inject it the normal way. BTW `element` is already a jQuery variable and does not need `$(element)` - providing you're loading jQuery before Angular.

```
Directives.directive('timeago', function($log) {
   return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
       element.attr('title', scope.post.utc_posted);
       element.timeago();
     }
   }
});
```